# "is an unknown property": custom properties in Spring's application.properties

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

Sorry if this a trivial thing, I'm hacking out on an abandoned project and trying to add a custom property to the projects `application.properties` file.

The properties actually work fine (i.e. they are properly resolved when doing `@Value("${foo.config.someValue"})`) but Eclipse insists on telling me this:

[image]

Pressing tab does nothing at all.

How can I make this go away? Can I define my custom properties somewhere? Or maybe this isn't the way at all to add custom configuration properties?

Comment: I think Eclipse is expecting you to be using `@ConfigurationProperties`.

Answer (score 1):

Since [STS 3.5.4](https://spring.io/blog/2015/03/18/spring-boot-support-in-spring-tool-suite-3-6-4#making-the-greeting-configurable), you should be able to get rid of this warning, and have it replaced by useful 'hover-over' text by using java-doc on an `@ConfigurationProperties` bean to auto-generate [configuration meta-data](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html). You should be able to do this with application.properties or, since [3.7.0](http://view-source:http://docs.spring.io/sts/nan/latest/NewAndNoteworthy.html), application.yml, (but so far, I can't get it to work with either).

Answer (score 1):

There is an [Eclipse Quick Fix](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/eclipse/eclipse_quick_fix.htm) to deal with the warning you mention available in STS since the 3.7.1.RELEASE https://issuetracker.springsource.com/browse/STS-4206

Otherwise, assuming you have defined your properties as `@ConfigurationProperties`, then you just need to ensure you have `spring-boot-configuration-processor` as an optional dependency as discussed here https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/configuration-metadata.html#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor

Answer (score 0):

Your project might be having [configuration metadata](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata), whether [generated](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/1.3.0.M2/reference/htmlsingle/#configuration-metadata-annotation-processor) or manual. If so, you would need to add your the metadata pertaining to the new property, and re-build the project.